# How to generate two random numbers that are divisible by each other?

Tags: python, performance, math, random

I wrote a simple math game that I can practice mental math. My concern is to make sure two numbers are always divisible by each other. I have tried the `while` loop to add 1 until it is divisible but it took too long:

```
import random
import operator

def random_problem():
  operators = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    'x': operator.mul,
    ':': operator.truediv
  };

  num1 = random.randint(1000,9999)
  num2 = random.randint(num1,9999)

  operation = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

  if operation == ':':
    while num1 % num2 != 0:
      num2 += 1
  
  answer = (operators.get(operation)(num1, num2))
  print(f'What is {num1} {operation} {num2}')
  return answer
```

So any ideas to make this process faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

1. Generate a random first number (`n1`)
2. Generate a random multiplier (`m`)
3. Use the product of the first number and the multiplier as the second number (`n2 = n1 * m`)

Answer (score 0):

**IIUC:**

Your current code will only work when `num1 == num2` for all other values of num2 the denominator is always greater than the numerator so the modulus will never be `0`, so you would get an infinite loop.

Instead try generating the numerator from the denominator like:

**Code:**

```
import random
import operator


def random_problem():
    operators = {
        # '+': operator.add,
        # '-': operator.sub,
        # 'x': operator.mul,
        ':': operator.truediv
    }

    num2 = random.randint(1000, 2000)
    num1 = num2 * random.randint(1, int(9999/num2))
    operation = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))

    if operation == ':':
        while num1 % num2 != 0:
            num2 += 1

    answer = (operators.get(operation)(num1, num2))
    print(f'What is {num1} {operation} {num2}')
    return answer

print(random_problem())
```

**Output:**

```
What is 4136 : 1034
4.0
```